# Julia: Create AbstractArray with Constraints on Values

Tags: struct, types, constructor, initialization, julia

I'm working on a Julia project which requires matrices to satisfy a trace-one constraint. To avoid checking if matrices are trace-one at inputs and outputs of numerous functions, I'd like to create a new data structure which implicitly contains this constraint.

In my working example, I've defined a struct `TraceOne` which throws an error if the trace is not equal to one.

```
struct TraceOne
    M :: Matrix{Complex{Float64}}
    TraceOne(M) = (tr(M) == 1) ? new(M) : throw(DomainError(M, "Matrix M is not trace-one."))
end

A = TraceOne([0.1 0.5;0.3 0.9])
```

However, I would like to avoid accessing the trace-one matrix with a key, `A.M` returns `[0.1 0.5;0.3 0.9]`.

Alternatively, I've tried to create a `struct` which is a SubType of an `AbstractMatrix`, but I can't get the values of the `AbstractMatrix` to initialize properly.

```
struct TraceOne2 <: AbstractMatrix{Complex{Float64}}
    M :: Matrix{Complex{Float64}}
    Base.size(T::TraceOne2) = size(T.M)
    Base.getindex(T::TraceOne2, I::Vararg{Int,2}) = getindex(T.M, size(T.M)...)
    Base.setindex!(T::TraceOne2, v, I::Vararg{Int,2}) = (T.M[I] = v)
    TraceOne2(M) = (tr(M) == 1) ? new(M) : throw(DomainError(M, "Matrix M is not trace-one."))
end

B = TraceOne2([0.1 0.5;0.3 0.9])
```

When I run this code, I find that `B` is `[0.9 0.9;0.9 0.9]`. All elements of `B` are initialized to the value of the `(2,2)`, the index of the input array.

How should I modify `struct TraceOne2 ... end` such that the resulting matrix `B` is initialized as `[0.1 0.5;0.3 0.9]`?

Comment: Your not supposed to put all the `Base.size` etc definitions _inside_ the struct. Does this actually work?

Answer (score 0):

Change this functions from:

```
Base.getindex(T::TraceOne2, I::Vararg{Int,2}) = getindex(T.M, size(T.M)...)
Base.setindex!(T::TraceOne2, v, I::Vararg{Int,2}) = (T.M[I] = v)
```

to:

```
Base.getindex(T::TraceOne2, I::Vararg{Int,2}) = getindex(T.M, I...)
Base.setindex!(T::TraceOne2, v, I::Vararg{Int,2}) = (T.M[I...] = v)
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly, simple mistake on my part :)